# Access Violation exception when running a release-built application

Tags: c++, release, access-violation

Recently I have been developing a small OpenGL game. Everything in it runs fine with the debug build but when I build the release, I get a strange Access Violation exception.

I searched across the code and it seems that the problem occurs when I try to open a file. Here is the function where I think the problem is coming from:

```
#define LOCAL_FILE_DIR "data\\"
#define GLOBAL_FILE_DIR "..\\data\\"

std::string FindFile(const std::string &baseName)
{
    std::string fileName = LOCAL_FILE_DIR + baseName;
    std::ifstream testFile(fileName.c_str()); // The code breaks here
    if(testFile.is_open())
        return fileName;

    fileName = GLOBAL_FILE_DIR + baseName;
    testFile.open(fileName.c_str());
    if(testFile.is_open())
        return fileName;

    throw std::runtime_error("Could not find the file " + baseName);
}
```

This code is associated with loading of GLSL shaders. A function takes the shader's file name and then passes it to FindFile in order to find the file needed.

Comment: I doubt the cause of the crash is in that code.

Comment: Check if your code contains any `assert`s.

Comment: `std::ifstream` constructor does not throw exceptions AFAIK

Comment: I don't have 'assert's in my code and I just wanted to say that the code breaks on that specific line.

Comment: What address are you attempting to accessing at the point of the access violation? Is it possible that `baseName` is referring to the result of dereferencing null, or is otherwise invalid?

Comment: A standard failure mode here is not at all checking for errors and hoping that the Debug build tells you what is wrong.  Doesn't work in the Release build, an obvious failure mode is not having the file in the same location since the build directory is different.

Comment: @AlanStokes I printed out `baseName` in my console. It is the right string: "PosColorLocalTransform.vert".

Comment: @HansPassant My Visual Studio is running with debug symbols enabled. AFAIK that is the way to Debug in Release build. And for the build directory, where could it be? I mean my Release and Debug folders for the project are in the same place.

Comment: Also if I only change the file name to something which doesn't exist it throws an exception that the file is not found (this is an expected behaviour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem.

Everything was happening because I have made the Release build using glsdk's Debug build libraries. Changing to the Release build libraries fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a general rule from personal (and teaching) experience: >90% of the cases where Debug works fine and Release crashes are due to uninitialized variables. That's a little harder to do in C++ than in C, but it is a very common problem. Make sure all your vars (like `baseName`) are initialized before using them.

Comment: Since `string` has a default constructor it is impossible to get one that's uninitialized. Still good general advice though.

Answer (score 0):

Check that baseName is valid. Try printing it out. You may be getting a corrupted copy of baseName or your stack may have gotten trashed prior to that point (same result).

Comment: I printed out `baseName` in the console and it is valid. Just the file name, no other symbols, no nothing.